# Getting sub total from another related table in Laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables, one is items which contains title, quantity and price, it connects with another table call orders, so it's one to many relationship. If i query order entries with items load as well how could i get the subtotal of each item, "qty x price = subtotal" and get the grand total of all items belong to the order entity. Can i do it with Laravel eloquent or i have to do that in raw sql query? can i create a virtual column for the sub-total?
to get the sum of any column from related table is easy
`$order->items->sum('unit_price')`
then the result should be

order 00001
item A     $10 x 5 = $50
item B     $15 x 2 = $30

grand total for order 00001 = $80

order 00002
item C     $1 x 5 = $5
item D     $5 x 2 = $10

grand total for order 00002 = $15

Comment: No, i didn't save that on order table or item table.

Comment: basically, order table is all about the information of the order related, item table has quantity and amount, i don't wanna save the subtotal which could be calculate afterward, i don't know the way.

Comment: I found a solution, create a virtual column in table item.  
```
ALTER TABLE items  ADD sub_total float(10,2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (unit_price * qty) VIRTUAL NOT NULL;
```